# automatically add a reference field in a table when some values are repeating?

Tags: excel, sqlite, csv, database-design

I have a CSV file that I can handle through Excel/LibreOffice and/or SQLite3. This task has to be performed only when the CSV is updated, which rarely happens, so I can run it by hand when needed.

Assume a table structured like this one, containing about 10k rows and many more columns. The SAME_COLOR column is empty.

This is the starting CSV/table:

| ID | product | COLOR | SAME_COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tshirt | black |  |
| 2 | shoes | white |  |
| 3 | pants | yellow |  |
| 4 | socks | black |  |
| 5 | hoodies | pink |  |
| 6 | bags | red |  |
| 7 | gloves | blue |  |
| 8 | bracelets | red |  |

If there is a row of the table that has the same value of another row in column COLOR (which can happen only two times inside the table, or never happen), I'd like to add in column SAME_COLOR, the ID of the other row with the same value.

This would be the output table:

| ID | product | COLOR | SAME_COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tshirt | black | 4 |
| 2 | shoes | white |  |
| 3 | pants | yellow |  |
| 4 | socks | black | 1 |
| 5 | hoodies | pink |  |
| 6 | bags | red | 8 |
| 7 | gloves | blue |  |
| 8 | bracelets | red | 6 |

ID 1 and ID 4 have the same COLOR, therefore:

- in row 1, in column SAME_COLOR is inserted the value 4
- in row 4, in column SAME_COLOR is inserted the value 1

ID 6 and ID 8 have the same COLOR, therefore:

- in row 6, in column SAME_COLOR is inserted the value 8
- in row 8, in column SAME_COLOR is inserted the value 6

This is the example CSV for the output table above:

```
ID,product,COLOR,SAME_COLOR
1,tshirt,black,4
2,shoes,white,
3,pants,yellow,
4,socks,black,1
5,hoodies,pink,
6,bags,red,8
7,gloves,blue,
8,bracelets,red,6
```

How do I do this fast/automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your description that there will only ever be two colors or one, in Excel 365 you can use the following formula:

*Note that I am using a **Table** with **structured references**, but you could change this to regular addressing if you prefer*

*With a Table, you need only enter the formula in `D2` and it will automatically fill down as far as needed*

- The formula makes use of the last optional argument of the `UNIQUE` function as combining the current ID with both ID's will result in only a single return value, or no return values => error.

```
=IFERROR(
    LET(
        f, FILTER([ID], [color] = [@color]),
        UNIQUE(VSTACK(f, [@ID]), , TRUE)
    ),
    ""
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have Office 2019 (no UNIQUE) and I tried it on the web based excel365 but I get a #NAME error value in every row. Any clue why this may happen?

Comment: solved. web based excel was set to a different region and wasn't translating the formula.